# duplicate rule only working for System Admin not for other profiles

Tags: profile, duplicate-management

I have created a duplicate rule with the below matching criteria:

```
(Account: Apart_NumEXACTMatchBlank = TRUE) AND
(Account: MailingStreetFUZZY: STREETMatchBlank = FALSE) AND
(Account: MailingCityFUZZY: CITYMatchBlank = FALSE)
```

This is working fine for system admin profile but duplicates are not detected for other profiles. Record-Level Security is maintained as 'Enforce Sharing rules'. Is the duplicates visibility based on 'Record-Level Security'?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the Record-Level Security to 'Bypass Sharing Rules'. Salesforce doesn’t display the record that the user doesn’t have access to. When the duplicate rule is set to bypass sharing rules, it operates on all potential duplicates regardless of ownership.
It is working for the system admin because the admin user has access to all the records.

Comment: I was missing the Apex controller access to the profile, it resolved my issue. Thank you